# Opengl: use a texture only to give alpha channel to a colored object

Tags: opengl, textures, alphablending

I'm new at OpenGL and I can't find out how to do this:
I want to render a letter and be able to change it's color, so I have a texture with the letter on a transparent background. I managed to render it using this code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

But that renders the letter in black, as it's on the texture. How can I render it with the color setted with `glColor4f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been messing with glTexEnv? If you did, call :

`glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE)`

and that will restore the default behaviour, which is to multiply the texture color with the vertex color.

Comment: Well, if the default behaviour is to multiply the texture color with the vertex color then I should have made my texture white instead of black, right?

Comment: Yes, but depends on what you passed to glColor4f.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I changed the texture color to white and now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of other possibilities. One would be to put the shape of the letter into the stencil buffer, and then draw a quad in your preferred color. Another would be to draw your text in light grey, and use lighting to have it displayed in the color you want.